# how do i use GetCurrentPosition function for IDirectSoundBuffer in windows in rust?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I am using the rust [windows](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/index.html) crate. I have a function which returns a (supposedly) valid [`IDirectSoundBuffer`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Media/Audio/DirectSound/struct.IDirectSoundBuffer.html):

```rust
fn init_sound() -> Option::<IDirectSoundBuffer> {
  ...
}
```

in my main function:

```rust
fn main() {
  let buffer = init_sound();
  let mut play_cursor = 0;
  let mut write_cursor = 0;
  if buffer.GetCurrentPosition(&mut play_cursor, &mut write_cursor) == Ok(()) {
    println!("got current position");
  } else {
    println!("failed");
    println!("{buffer:?}";
  }
}
```

however, despite outputting a valid `Option::<IDirectSoundBuffer>` from `init_sound`: `Some(IDirectSoundBuffer(IUnknown(0x1d52989ca60)))`, `GetCurrentPosition` still goes to the `else` statement and prints out

```
failed
IDirectSoundBuffer(IUnknown(0x1d52989ca60))
```

may I know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: GetCurrentPosition returns an HRESULT (an int32). What is its value?

Comment: `init_sound()` should really return a `Result<IDirectSoundBuffer>` instead, and `main` consequently `Result<()>`. This allows you to use the `?`-operator for error propagation. Though if `buffer` is an `Option` why does this even compile? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: [Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) explains how errors are reported and propagated in Rust. If you haven't worked through that chapter in the Rust Book you should.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with this: I have never seen a `Result` value checked with  `== Ok(())`. Generally it's better to use the `.is_ok()` function. But in your case that also isn't very suitable. You shouldn't be discarding the `Result`. If it returned `Err`, you should take a look at `Err`'s value - usually that will contain the information you need to understand what the problem is.

You can start off with something like this:

```
let res = buffer.GetCurrentPosition(&mut play_cursor, &mut write_cursor);
println!("{res:?}");
```

Also, you might want to check the `mut` params when the call is successful.

The above advice is just to help you figure out what's happening. In production code, error handling is of utmost importance, so make sure you learn how it should be done properly.